# How to get the text of an anchor tag selected by xPath() using selenium and Mocha

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, mocha.js

I have successfully selected an `<a>` tag. I want to display the text of the anchor tag and I am unable to do so.

I am using selenium, mocha, javascript and phantomJS

Here's my script(full in detail):

```
var assert = require('assert');
var test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var By = webdriver.By;
var until = webdriver.until;
var equals = webdriver.equals;

/*-------login details--------*/
var userAdmin = 'saswat@matrixnmedia.com';
var passAdmin = 'DarkPrince2012';

var userTradeshow = 'joni@mailinator.com';
var passTradeshow = 'Mithun@';
/*-----login details ends-----*/

/*---setting up credentials---*/
var passArgument = process.env.KEY; /*fetch value from the environment value;*/
console.log("You chose to enter as '"+passArgument+"'");
if(passArgument.toLowerCase().indexOf("admin")>-1)
{
    var username = userAdmin,
        password = passAdmin;
}
else if(passArgument.toLowerCase().indexOf("trade")>-1)
{
    var username = userTradeshow,
        password = passTradeshow;
}   
else
{
    var username = "",
        password = "";
}    
/*-setting up credentials ends-*/

test.describe('TrackRevenue Test', function() 
{
  test.it('should work', function() 
  {
        var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
                    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs())
                    .build();
        var loginFlag = 0;
        var baseUrl = 'http://saswatr3.ouh.co/login';
        var expectedTitle = "Track Revenue";
        var successMessage = "Welcome to the admin page!";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        driver.getTitle().then(function(title) 
        {
            if(expectedTitle === title)
            {
                console.log("Verification Successful - The correct title is displayed on the web page.");
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Verification Failed - An incorrect title is displayed on the web page.");
            }
        });
        driver.findElement(By.id('username')).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.id('password')).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.id('_submit')).click();
        driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Log out')]")).then(function(elements_arr)
        {
            if(elements_arr.length > 0)
            {
                loginFlag = 1;
                driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'user-name m-r-sm text-muted welcome-message')]")).then(function(e){
                    if(e.length > 0)
                    {
                        console.log("No. of elements :"+e.length);
                        console.log("Found The USerName : ");
                        console.log("Username : "+e[0].text);//this is the line with the issue. It prints undefined
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Invalid credentials.')]")).then(function(elements_arr2)
                {
                   if(elements_arr2.length > 0)
                        console.log("Login Unsuccessful, div invalid credentials found");
                   else
                        console.log("Login Unsuccessful, div invalid credentials not found");
                });
            } 
            if(loginFlag == 1)
                console.log("Login Successful");
            else
                console.log("Login Unsuccessful");
        });
    driver.quit();
  });
});
```

#### 1. Case 1: With e[0].text

My problem lies within this script.

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'user-name m-r-sm text-muted welcome-message')]")).then(function(e){
                        if(e.length > 0)
                        {
                            console.log("No. of elements :"+e.length);
                            console.log("Found The USerName : ");
                            console.log("Username : "+e[0].text);//this is the line with the issue. It prints undefined
                        }
                    });
```

As you can see, `console.log("Username : "+e[0].text);` is causing problem.

For convenience, this is the full message I am getting.

```
    C:\xampp\htdocs\testPhantomJS\node_modules\selenium-webdriver>env KEY=trade moch
a -t 120000 testMocha/login-as-administrator-mocha.js
You chose to enter as 'trade'


  TrackRevenue Test
Verification Successful - The correct title is displayed on the web page.
Login Successful
No. of elements :1
Found The USerName :
Username : undefined
    √ should work (71593ms)


  1 passing (1m)
```

#### 2. Case 2: With e.text

Now, when I made the changes like:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'user-name m-r-sm text-muted welcome-message')]")).then(function(e){
                        if(e.length > 0)
                        {
                            console.log("No. of elements :"+e.length);
                            console.log("Found The USerName : ");
                            console.log("Username : "+e.text);//this is the line with the issue. It prints undefined
                        }
                    });
```

This is the message I get.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\testPhantomJS\node_modules\selenium-webdriver>env KEY=trade moch
a -t 120000 testMocha/login-as-administrator-mocha.js
You chose to enter as 'trade'


  TrackRevenue Test
Verification Successful - The correct title is displayed on the web page.
Login Successful
No. of elements :1
Found The USerName :
Username : undefined
    √ should work (87006ms)


  1 passing (1m)
```

#### 3. Case 3: With e[0].getText()

I made the following changes:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'user-name m-r-sm text-muted welcome-message')]")).then(function(e){
                    if(e.length > 0)
                    {
                        console.log("No. of elements :"+e.length);
                        console.log("Found The USerName : ");
                        console.log("Username : "+e[0].getText());
                    }
                });
```

Here's the message:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\testPhantomJS\node_modules\selenium-webdriver>env KEY=trade moch
a -t 120000 testMocha/login-as-administrator-mocha.js
You chose to enter as 'trade'


  TrackRevenue Test
Verification Successful - The correct title is displayed on the web page.
Login Successful
No. of elements :1
Found The USerName :
Username : Promise::456 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}
    √ should work (37212ms)


  1 passing (37s)
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
   <li>
      <a class="user-name m-r-sm text-muted welcome-message" href="/profile/">saswat@matrixnmedia.com</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="http://saswatr3.ouh.co/main/account/help.php">
      <i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i>
   </a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a class="log-out" href="/logout">
      <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>
       Log out
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you provide us the html code with the anchor tag you want to get?

Comment: i think it is `e.getText().then(...`, [docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebElement.html#getText)

Comment: Because 'undefined' is returning, it looks like you aren't actually getting an element with your xpath. Can you double-check the xpath against the HTML, or post the HTML?

Comment: In that case, how come the `console.log("No. of elements :"+e.length);
                            console.log("Found The USerName : ");` is displaying? If the element can't be selected, then this LOC also shouldn't be printing anything. Right?

Comment: can you post your HTML, at least the part around the anchor tag you're interested in, maybe you're hunting the wrong element, we can only know if you post your HTML. cheers

Comment: OK, sure! Just give me a minute. @drkthng

Comment: Added the html, @drkthng

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'user-name m-r-sm text-muted welcome-message')]")).getText().then(function(text){
                           console.log("Username : " + text);
                        });
```

- you only need to search via findElement (not findElements)
- and directly extract the text before the function part

UPDATE:

Sometimes the object is not really hidden, but also not in the viewport, then gettext() also returns an empty String.
To check try the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'user-name m-r-sm text-muted welcome-message')]")).getAttribute("innerText").then(function(text){
                           console.log("Username : " + text);
                        });
```

Comment: `Username :     `, it came totally blank

Comment: added another thing you could try

Comment: Great! That did the charm. :)

Comment: Thanks bro. I was just circling around with all the possibilities. But this one did the charm.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the plural findElement**s**, which gives you a list of elements. Using e.text against the list won't work because you can only use .text with a webobject.

Use the singular version to get the first match on the page: **driver.findElement()**

If you do need to get the text of only one element in a list, use **e[0].text** to get the text of the first element in the list.